# Do I, as a druid, add the spells from the Gruul Anarch background to my list of spells that I can prepare anytime?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, background

I am currently playing a druid and took the Gruul Anarch background (Guildmasters Guide to Ravnica). The background comes with additional guild spells. would those spells be available to be prepared after a long rest?

Comment: Are you actually playing a Ravnica campaign where guild membership is part of your character, or did you just choose the background in a non-Ravnica campagin?

Answer (score 5):

#### Guild spells are added to your class's spell list.

The rules for [Gruul Guild Spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/ggtr/gruul-clans#GruulGuildSpells) state:

> For you, the spells on the Gruul Guild Spells table are added to the spell list of your spellcasting class.

And the [druid's spell preparation rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#Spellcasting-166) state:

> You prepare the list of druid spells that are available for you to cast, choosing **from the druid spell list**.

Since as a druid your guild spells are added to the druid spell list, you can prepare them as a druid.